# Folder-like menu css

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm working with a table-like menu but I can't do it. Here is my CSS.
I'm using bootstrap 5. I can't adjust the padding and also the color of the menu when it's active or not.

```
.top-nav{
margin-left:0px;
}

.top-bar a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}


.top-bar{
border-bottom: 100px solid white;
border-left: 0 solid transparent;
border-right: 80px solid transparent;
border-top: 80px;
height: 0;
width: 200px;
clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 15px 0px 0px 0px)
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
      <div class="row top-nav">
            <div class="col-md-3 top-bar">
                <a class="fw-bold text-primary" href="#home">Users</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 top-bar">
                <a class="fw-bold text-primary" href="#home">Warehouse Admin</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 top-bar">
                <a class="fw-bold text-primary" href="#home">Sales Rep</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 top-bar">
                <a class="fw-bold text-primary" href="#home">Senior Sales Rep</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My work
[image: My Work]

This the expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the snippet and change variables as you like

```css
.folders {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.tab {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px 16px;
  border-top-right-radius: 16px 16px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 17.5px;
}

.tab.active {
  z-index: 100;
  background: #fff;
}

.tab:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 35px solid gray;
  left: 145px;
  border-top: 35px solid transparent;
  bottom: 0;
}

.tab.active:after {
  border-left: 35px solid #fff;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="folders">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab active"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your a css master